# Can we make ligatures copy-and-pastable?

Tags: ligatures, copy-paste

Is there a straightforward way to make ligatures more copy-and-pastable? I know that by using

```
\usepackage[t1]{fontenc}
```

that many glyphs like accented and umlauted characters become copy-and-pastable from a pdf.

But, for example, the word "five" is typeset with an "fi" ligature (a merging of the two letters into one) and I'm unable to copy this word from the pdf and paste into a text editor. The `fontenc` package doesn't seem to help with this.

Here is my MWE of the issue. I am using Adobe Reader X to read, and Windows with TeXnikCenter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
five

\end{document}
```

I have tested and cannot successfully paste into TeXnicCenter, MS Word, or the Firefox address bar.

Comment: Hmm. I get `five`. What PDF reader are you using?

Comment: I can also not reproduce this. Could you post a minimal example that shows the behaviour?

Comment: Ok, I edited the question.

Comment: Try `\input{glyphtounicode}
  \pdfgentounicode=1`.

Comment: @Stephan That seems to do it. Do you want to post as an answer? Are you aware of any unwanted side effects this could have?

Comment: None that I know of. At least as long as you're using `pdftex`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general, to enable copy/paste from `pdftex`-generated PDF,

```
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

should be used.