# Why isn't XeTeX properly mapping this Th ligature to T_h?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I realize I am using a proprietary font here, but this is where I discovered this problem (it also applies to other ligatures as well as old style numbers).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
        Path = M:/MyStuff/Fonts/timesnewroman6.80/,
        UprightFont = times.ttf,
        Ligatures = Discretionary]{tnr}
\begin{document}
Th
\end{document}
```

[image]

When I copy and paste this from the pdf, on the other hand, I get  instead of the expected `Th`. Looking at how this ligature has been encoded (using FontForge), everything seems to have been done properly:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the resulting PDF available any where?

Comment: You mean you want the actual file? It's now here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03340620415189837770

Comment: Could it be, that you need something along these lines: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86614/can-we-make-ligatures-copy-and-pastable

Comment: @canaaerus No, glyphtounicode is for pdfTeX, not XeTeX. Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110354/pdfglyphtounicode-with-xetex

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately in the pdf file you provided I can not select `th` as text with my pdf reader `okular`. Is the font you use publicly available, so we could try to compile the document ourselves?

Comment: @canaaerus No, I'm afraid not. It's propitiatory, as I apologized for in my question. It's the Times New Roman font that came with Windows 8 (the font version is 6.80).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Times New Roman font (at least the version shipped with Windows) has a version 3 [`post`](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/post.htm) table which does not include any glyph names (`post` is the table that contains glyph names in TrueType fonts). As a result, the PDF driver (`xdvipdfmx`) will give the glyph synthetic names; for unencoded glyph like this it will simply be `glyphXXXX` where `XXXX` is the glyph id.

The names you see in FontForge UI are simply synthetic names generated by FontForge itself, and it seems to apply some heuristic to guess glyph names for unencoded glyphs based on font’s glyph substitution rules.

`xdvipdfmx` does not currently do such a heuristic as it would require parsing the `GSUB` table of the font (which is not something the driver usually does; the OpenType layout is done by XeTeX itself), and is not always bulletproof (what if the same glyph is re-used for two different ligatures?).

Comment: I see. Meaning, I understand your explanation (but have no idea how you figured that out). Relatedly, I've found that the Th ligature works fine with LuaTeX. Is that expected behavior? Does LuateX make some guess in this case what the glyph name is? If you're interested in the LuaTeX output pdf: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02282326599062751228

Comment: I think LuaTeX guesses a proper glyph name based on the fact that it is a ligature (would be interesting to see what happens if one inserts the glyph directly using its font id), unfortunately this information is not available to `xdvipdfmx` at the time of PDF creation.

Comment: I can find out if you tell me how I do that. I'm used to inserting glyphs directly from fonts with ``\char"XXXX``, where XXXX is the Unicode points, but glyphs like these don't have Unicode points.

Comment: Check http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120762/729.

Comment: You're expecting too much of me ... I don't understand how to modify that answer to fit my case.

Comment: Never-mind, I forgot that LuaTeX uses a FontForge-based font loader, that is probably where the T_h mapping came from.