# Convert bbl to plain text

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm trying to submit an article to a journal with an automated system that requires a list of references in plain text. Is there some way of automatically converting my bbl file into plain text (something that I can just copy and paste into a text box, without ligatures etc)?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik No worries, thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe Moewe's answer here has a solution for you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436780/29873

Comment: Did https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435658/35864 help? I'm afraid I'd pretty much write the same answer to this question here, so I'm inclined to say this is a duplicate.

Comment: @moewe didn't see it, but it is very similar.