# Replace citation keys in Latex file with formatted literature reference

Tags: biblatex, formatting, citing

I have a Latex file with citation keys which are translated into formatted literature references in the pdf (I use biblatex). Let us assume I want to have the formatted footnotes, as I see them in the pdf text, in the latex file, for whatever reason.

I can only think of the manual solution, I could manually copy each reference in the pdf file, replace the citation key in the latex file with the copied reference, and edit the reference appropriately (for instance include \textit{} for the title of the book etc.)

Is there any smart and faster way to do this?

Edit: I use a bib-file which include the relevant information for the literature references

Edit 2: To clarify: Let's say I use this minimal example and bib file from here ([The most basic biblatex example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141957/the-most-basic-biblatex-example))

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
As first example citation here is \cite{Chomsky1957}. 
Here is another example citation \cite{Labov1972}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is the Bib File

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
\end{filecontents}
```

When I compile the PDF I will receive a formatted citation

[image]

Is there any smart way to replace in the Latex file the citation key "\cite{Chomsky1957}" with the formatted reference that can be found in the PDF (Chomsky, Noam, 1957, *Syntactic Structures*. Mouton, The Hague.)

The aim would be to have a latex file which already contains the formatted references

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking here - you want what would normally be a citation to look like a full reference as would normally be found in the bibliography?

Comment: seems related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435658/create-text-file-of-references

Comment: Basically no. `biblatex` typesets the citations (and bibliography entries) in such a way that the equivalent "plain-text LaTeX code" is not easily accessed (it might be possible to export and re-import LaTeX into different formats). There is `biblatex2bibitem` as a workaround that works OK in many simple cases (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/624703/35864), but it is by no means universal.

Comment: Ok, thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a `biblatex` solution, because referencing [Create text-file of references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435658/create-text-file-of-references) we see that

> there is no easy way to obtain the text of the bibliography as it is
> printed by \printbibliography

So, this solution focuses on the `bibtex` part from the above link, using `plain-plain.bst` from https://gist.github.com/moewew/50795d6f171269e949d71d8c4149468e.

### `myfile.tex` (your mwe modified slightly)

I'm using the following modified version of your file, which does *not* use `biblatex`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}


\begin{document}
As first example citation here is \cite{Chomsky1957}. 
Here is another example citation \cite{Labov1972}

\bibliographystyle{plain-plain}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}
```

### `plain-plain.bst` (slightly modified version)

I'm using `plain-plain.bst` (linked above) with the following modification:

```
...
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  ""
  newline$
  "bib-key-begin---" write$
  cite$ write$
  "---bib-key-end" write$
  newline$
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
...
```

I put this file in `~/texmf/bibtex/bst/plain-plain.bst` and ran `texhash ~/texmf`

This means that I run the mwe, then I receive

### `myfile.bbl`

```
bib-key-begin---Chomsky1957---bib-key-end
Noam Chomsky. Syntactic Structures. Mouton, The Hague, 1957.


bib-key-begin---Labov1972---bib-key-end
William Labov. Sociolinguistic Patterns. University of Pennsylvania Press,
  Philadelphia, 1972.
```

This is a plain text version of the bibliography. From here, we need to read this into the `.tex` file and replace the `\cite{<key>}` with the appropriate value.

You can use any kind of text processing for this; I'd use `latexindent.pl` (disclaimer, I'm the author) and the following file:

### `latexindent.yaml`

```yaml
replacements:
  -
    when: after
    substitution: |-
        s^\A(.*)\Z^
           my $body = $1;
           # read in .bbl file
           my $bblFile = ${$self}{fileName};
           $bblFile =~ s/\.tex/.bbl/s;
           my $bblBody = q();
           my $openFilePossible = 1;
           open( BBLFILE, $bblFile ) or ( $openFilePossible = 0 );
           if ( $openFilePossible == 1 ) {
              $bblBody = $bblBody.$_  while (<BBLFILE>);
              close(BBLFILE);
           }
           # split the bbl file at bib-key-begin
           my @bibentries = split(/bib-key-begin---/,$bblBody);
           # loop through the bibliography items
           my $index = 0;
           foreach (@bibentries){
                next if ($_ !~ m/---bib-key-end/s);
                $_ =~ s/(.*?)---bib-key-end//s;
                my $bibKey = $1;
                my $bibValue = $_;
                $bibValue =~ s/\R//sg;
                # make the substitution in the .tex file
                #   \cite{<key>} with <value>
                $body =~ s/\\cite\{$bibKey\}/$bibValue/sg;
           }; 
           $body;^sgxe
```

and now run

```
latexindent.pl -rr -l myfile.tex
```

and the final output is

### myfile.tex (final output)

```tex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}


\begin{document}
As first example citation here is Noam Chomsky. Syntactic Structures. Mouton, The Hague, 1957.. 
Here is another example citation William Labov. Sociolinguistic Patterns. University of Pennsylvania Press,  Philadelphia, 1972.

\bibliographystyle{plain-plain}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}
```

### final comment

If you need `myfile.bbl` to contain bold/italics, then you'll have to tweak `plain-plain.bst`.